# React Native cant set image as background

Tags: image, react-native, background, render

I've been trying to set an image as background on a react native app, without success.

Here is my Image tag.

```
<Image
source={require('../img/cat.jpg')}
style={styles.backgroundImage}
blurRadius={1} />
```

It is supossed to contain children element, that should render on top.

The style is as it follows:

```
backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
```

At the moment, children element are rendered on bottom of screen, after the image, and not on top of it.

How im supossed to make this work?

Comment: Could this medium post maybe help you ? https://medium.com/reactnative/background-images-in-react-native-191f3ed95a45

Answer (score 1):

RN now provides the `<ImageBackground>` component as [described in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) and used as

```
 return (
  <ImageBackground source={...}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
 );
```

Alternatively, you can use `position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, resizeMode: 'stretch'//or 'contain'`
with your Image styling.